# python : TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

So I've been trying to complete a spell_checker that takes a .txt and compare with the dictionary.txt to find incorrect words. the result should be print back the words from the .txt that are wrong.

But I keep getting this error when trying to do my for loop:

TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Here are my codes:

```
def spell_check(wordlist):
    opening = open('words.txt').read(). lower(). strip(' ')
    text = []
    conv = set(opening)
    conv1 = set(wordlist)
    conv2 = conv1.add
    return [x for x in conv if x not in conv2]
```

EDIT:
I needed conv2, because i need to keep the errors in the same orders they are present; I don't want it to be ordered like a set. so if anyone has other insights on how to solve this problem as well. that would be great.

If anyone can shine some light on this, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that this.... `conv = set(opening)` ... does what you expect. Hint: at no point do you split the text you read from the file into words...

Comment: Is `wordlist` the dictionary, and 'words.txt' the document you're spellchecking?

Comment: Same exact post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394789/python-how-to-make-a-spell-checker-that-outputs-the-wrong-words

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access `conv2` as an iterable, though you've set it to be equal to the method `add()`... What are you doing in your line:

```
conv2 = conv1.add
```

This is the problem line... I think you're looking for something other than `.add`, that is just going to assign `conv2` to be equal to the function (you could, for instance, say `conv2(2)`, equivalent to `conv1.add(2)`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding the method `add` to the variable `conv2`.  I think what you may have meant to do is this:

```
def spell_check(wordlist):
    # change .strip(' ') to .split(' ') to get a list
    opening = open('words.txt').read().lower().split(' ')
    conv = set(opening)
    conv1 = set(wordlist)

    # I don't think you need conv2 at all, right?
    return [x for x in conv if x not in conv1]
```

I am assuming that `wordlist`, which gets passed in, is the dictionary, and 'words.txt' is the document you're spellchecking.